# Pilha dinâmica - C

Tags: c, alocação, stack

Estou estudando pilha dinâmica a partir do código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define tam 50

// ---- Estruturas para os tipos -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct                          // Definicao da estrutura do registro
{                                       // Com definição do tipo (typedef)
       int   Chave;
       // Outros campos
}REGISTRO;

// ---- Funções ligadas aos REGISTROs --------------------------------------------------------------------------
REGISTRO LerRegistro()                  // Ler os dados de um registro
{
    REGISTRO r;

    printf("\n\n Digite a chave da pessoa : ");
    scanf("%d", &r.Chave);

    // Outros campos
    return r;          
}

void ImprimeRegistro(REGISTRO r)        // Imprimir um registro
{
     printf(" Chave : %d \n",   r.Chave);
    // Outros campos
}


// --- Tipo PILHA ---------------------------------------------
struct TNo{
       REGISTRO         reg;
       struct TNo       *prox;
};

typedef struct TNo *TPILHA; //não entendi o motivo da criação dessa //struct

void InicializarPilha(TPILHA *pPilha)
{
    (*pPilha) = NULL;
}


int PilhaCheia(TPILHA pPilha)
{
    return 0;
}

int PilhaVazia(TPILHA pPilha)
{
    return (pPilha == NULL);
}


void Empilhar(TPILHA *pPilha, REGISTRO pReg )
{
    struct TNo *novo;// pq essa struct foi criada?

    novo = (struct TNo *) malloc(sizeof (struct TNo));
    novo->reg     = pReg;
    novo->prox    = NULL;// pq o valor do próximo é nulo?

    if (*pPilha == NULL)
    {
        (*pPilha) = novo;//o que essa linha quer dizer?
    }
    else
    {
        novo->prox = (*pPilha); //o que essa linha quer dizer?
        (*pPilha) = novo; //o que essa linha quer dizer?
    }
}

REGISTRO Desempilhar(TPILHA *pPilha)
{
    REGISTRO aux;

    if (*pPilha == NULL)
    {
        aux.Chave = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        aux = (*pPilha)->reg;
        (*pPilha) = (*pPilha)->prox;
    }
    return aux;
}

void Visualizar(TPILHA pPilha)
{
    TPILHA aux1 = pPilha;

    printf("\n\n");
    while (aux1 != NULL)
    {
          printf(" %d \n", aux1->reg.Chave);
          aux1 = aux1->prox;
    }                                             
    printf(" ------- ");
    printf("\n\n");
}


// ---- Funções Uteis --------------------------------------------------------------------------
char Menu2()                            // Menu com retorno da 
                                        // opcao selecionada
{
    char o;

    printf(" -- Menu -- \n");
    printf("  ( A ) Adicionar ao Estoque \n");
    printf("  ( R ) Retirar do estoque \n");
    printf("  ( > ) Transferir da Pilha 1 para a Pilha 2 \n");
    printf("  ( < ) Transferir da Pilha 2 para a Pilha 1 \n");
    printf("  ( V ) Visualizar Estoque \n");
    printf("  ( S ) Sair \n");
    printf("\n  Opcao :  ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &o);

    return o;    
}

main()
{
    TPILHA p1, p2;
    char     opcao;

    InicializarPilha(&p1);
    InicializarPilha(&p2);

    do
    {   opcao = Menu2();   
        switch(opcao)
        {
           case 'A': case 'a':
                     {
                      // Solicitar qual pilha
                      printf(" Digite qual pilha : ");
                      int p;
                      scanf("%d", &p);

                      // Qual registro
                      REGISTRO aux;
                      printf(" Digite qual codigo : ");
                      scanf("%d", &aux.Chave);

                      // Empilhar
                      if (p==1)
                            Empilhar(&p1, aux); 
                      else
                            Empilhar(&p2, aux); 
                     } break;
           case 'R': case 'r': {
                      // Solicitar qual pilha
                      printf(" Digite qual pilha : ");
                      int p;
                      scanf("%d", &p);

                      // Desempilhar
                      if (p==1)
                            Desempilhar(&p1); 
                      else
                            Desempilhar(&p2); 
                     }break;
            case '<': {
                       REGISTRO raux;
                       raux = Desempilhar(&p2);
                       Empilhar(&p1, raux);
                    }break;
            case '>': {// Mover de Pilha 1 para Pilha 2
                       REGISTRO raux;
                       raux = Desempilhar(&p1);//Desemp de P1
                       Empilhar(&p2, raux);    //Emp em P2
                    }break;
            case 'V': case 'v': {
                      printf("pilha 1 :\n ");
                      Visualizar(p1);
                      printf("\n ----- \n ");
                      printf("pilha 2 :\n ");
                      Visualizar(p2);
                      printf("\n\n\n ");
                    }break; 
           case 's':
           case 'S': printf(" Opcao SAIR    escolhida \n"); break;
           default : printf(" Opcao invalida. \n");
        }
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
    }    
    while( (opcao != 'S') && (opcao != 's') );
}
```

Eu sei montar a estrutura, mas estou em duvida em algumas partes que estão comentadas no código, no caso o que as linhas especificas fazem

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct TNo *TPILHA; //não entendi o motivo da criação dessa //struct
```

Isso não cria uma `struct`. É apenas um `typedef` que diz que um ponteiro para a estrutura `TNo` se passa a chamar `TPILHA`. Na verdade esse tipo de typedefs são desaconcelhados pois dificultam a leitura porque escondem o ponteiro. Algo semelhante ainda que mais simples para perceber seria:

```
typedef int inteiro;
```

Que significa que `inteiro` passa a ser um tipo equivalente a `int` e permite então fazer algo como `inteiro x = 10;`

Quanto aos comentários na função `Empilhar`:

```
void Empilhar(TPILHA *pPilha, REGISTRO pReg )
{
    struct TNo *novo;// pq essa struct foi criada? (1)

    novo = (struct TNo *) malloc(sizeof (struct TNo));
    novo->reg     = pReg;
    novo->prox    = NULL;// pq o valor do próximo é nulo? (2)

    if (*pPilha == NULL)
    {
        (*pPilha) = novo;//o que essa linha quer dizer? (3)
    }
    else
    {
        novo->prox = (*pPilha); //o que essa linha quer dizer? (4)
        (*pPilha) = novo; //o que essa linha quer dizer? (5)
    }
}
```

1) Mais uma vez esta linha também não cria uma `struct`, apenas declara um ponteiro para uma estrutura `TNo`. A criação apenas vem na linha seguinte com o `malloc`.

2) O valor do próximo é nulo porque dá jeito iniciar o novo elemento com alguma coisa, e quando está vazia o necessário é `NULL` que simboliza que não tem mais elementos à frente. Nos casos em que não está vazia o `prox` vai novamente ser alterado, na linha que eu assinalei como (4). Dava para fazer de outra forma claro mas esta tem tendência a ser mais simples, para o resto do código que a função tem.

3) Aqui está a alterar a pilha que recebeu como ponteiro. Se a pilha está vazia pois é `NULL` então vai passar a ser o novo nó que foi criado. Como recebeu a pilha como ponteiro tem de alterar com o `*` utilizando a sintaxe `*ptr = valor;`.

4) Se a pilha não está vazia então o novo elemento criado tem de apontar para o ultimo que estava na pilha, dado por `*pPilha`, ou seja, o valor apontado por `pPilha`.

5) Esta instrução é a mesma que a 3).

Agora pessoalmente acho que ficou bem complicado a nível de sintaxe e lógica. Bem mais simples seria:

```
void Empilhar(TPILHA *pPilha, REGISTRO pReg )
{
    struct TNo *novo = malloc(sizeof (struct TNo));
    novo->reg     = pReg;
    novo->prox    = *pPilha;
    *pPilha       = novo;
}
```

Tão poucas linhas para fazer o mesmo! Ideias por detrás desta transformação:

- Fazer `*pPilha =` ou `(*pPilha) =` é o mesmo pois os parentesis são redundantes neste caso.
- `(*pPilha) = novo;` estava no `if` e no `else` logo não depende do `if` e deve vir depois
- `novo->prox = *pPilha;` - Se coloca o `prox` a `NULL` quando `*pilha` é `NULL` e coloca `prox` a `*pilha` quando não é então corresponde a colocar sempre `*pilha` que é bem mais simples.
- `= malloc(sizeof (struct TNo));` o *cast* no `malloc` não é necessário e acaba por simplificar a leitura entre outras coisas sem ele.